# Do I need to add every one of my URL referrer of my website to API to have google maps working?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm new to coding, and this new `google maps API`.

I've created Credential, and copied key over to my website.
I've added specific `URL` referrers on `API` that relates to the pages that show google maps on my website. Works great and google maps is working, but only on those specific pages.
I'm wondering if there's a way of instead of adding every single specific `URL` in `API` that shows my google maps, have one **referrer** that will allows every page on my site?

e.g. Instead of adding multiple referrers in API such as `www.example.com/group1/page1", then "/page2", "page3" etc, a referrer like www.example.com/every-page`

Hope this all makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use * wildcard character to ensure that all pages from your domain can include google maps. You do not need to specify each page separately.

```
www.example.com/*
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought I tried it and wasn't sure what a wildcard was. Seems to be working. Thanks.